# What to pad flashable images with?

Tags: embedded, padding, firmware

Dumb question... I'm stitching various parts (kernel, FS, etc.) to create a firmware image that will be flashed on NOR flash. Right now I'm padding the remaining space with zeros. Is there any convention / benefits of using other padding?

Comment: I always used zeros.  Just be sure to remain consistent as you will want to checksum/CRC the thing to make sure nothing went wrong.

Comment: most of the devices I have used erased is all ones 0xFF, although after 10-20 years I finally came across an erase with zeros device.  it shouldnt really matter in the grand scheme of things, places where it would you are probably not dealing with.  as already mentioned if you have a checksum, most make sure the padding is deep enough.

Comment: one place where it may help, is for example all ones is an invalid ARM instruction, I have not researched other instruction sets.  So if your code wanders off into this area of the flash (if this is even possible in your environment) then if its an ARM it will go to the undefined instruction.  all zeros is (depending on the arm instruction set) a valid instruction so it will run to the end of flash or to the end of your padding or flash or wrap around.  Might not do any harm but an undefined on the first fetch may help debugging.  YMMV with other architectures/ISAs.

Comment: there is no doubt a reason why the erase state is the erase state for a technology.  if you go with the erase state for that part then the bits ideally wont change. but perhaps you want to go against the erase state and use a crc to see if any bits decay/erase, fail now instead of some day in the future when that space is used by a firmware upgrade or more data.  just a though.

Comment: @old_timer Good point.

Comment: Some people tend to use 0xaa55 (all alternate bits set) for no other reason as to clearly distinguish it from "not initialized" = 0.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer 0xFF (on those devices where that is the erased state), for a couple of reasons.

- The write to flash will go faster, since the unused region doesn't have to change.
- Some devices have a limit on the number of re-flash cycles. I prefer not to write if I don't have to.
- On many devices, if the area is already erased then you don't have to go through the erase cycle to write new data. This can be handy, especially when what you are writing is data, not code.  You are not likely to want to add to the code without re-writing all of it, but you may want to add to parameter data which is stored in flash.